# Creating Chrome browser extension to filter non-html text file content?

Tags: javascript

I don't have any experience with browser extension development (and limited JS experience), so this is more of a general question, checking feasibility and maybe getting some pointers where to start.

I am thinking of writing a browser extension (Chrome preferred) which applies filters on plain text files displayed by the browser. I would like to have the extension process text line-by-line, and applying typical string-processing tasks, like searching for substrings, maybe regex, then removing certain parts of the line. (Application is the cleanup of log files, e.g. removal of redundant time stamps)

Apparently, (Chrome) browser extensions work as an additional piece of Javascript, which is executed and then alters the DOM tree. However, with the browser just displaying a plain text file, there is no DOM tree, I assume.

Questions:

- can JS extensions even be started properly when there is no HTML/DOM tree?
- Do I have a JS object to alter, in case plain text file is loaded? Do I have the document object, and maybe some property like "text"?
- Are there any examples I could base this kind of project on?

Thanks!

Comment: 1 & 2: Check the browser developer tools when you load such a site - things change, browsers are different, I seem to recall that it's possible (or WAS possible) in Firefox many years ago - never use chrome, so wouldn't know ... 3. If it's possible, then I dare say there is an example somewhere on the internet - that's what search engines are for (because you won't get an answer to that here)

Comment: I just tried a text file - chrome has `<html><head><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">The text</pre></body></html>` - so, you have a DOM (Firefox is similar)

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks! thats a good starting point. I know how to use search engines, of course, but checking feasibility in a mostly unknown terrain isnt always easy.